# Codeigniter email - browser keeps on loading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to send email using codeigniter.

```
<?php
class email_page extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        $config = Array(
                'protocol'=>'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => '465',
                'smtp_user' => 'testmail@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'password'
            );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');

        $this->email->from('testmail@gmail.com','Sender name');
        $this->email->to('testmail@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Test mail');
        $this->email->message('This is a test mail from codeigniter');

        if($this->email->send()){
            echo "Your mail was sent successfully!!!";
        }
        else{
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

The page keeps on loading and does not give any result. The code looks fine to me. Are there any errors? Thanks

Comment: Is your SMTP credential right ? do you have any error log ?

Comment: Instead of  gmail use http://mandrill.com/

Comment: I got this error after sometime..Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\system\libraries\Email.php on line 1870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found the answer.

```
 $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
```

Changed the above line to

```
 $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

I am not sure how this can happen.

Comment: what is difference between these lines?

Answer (score 1):

change your account settings here

```
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found error, just change port to 25

```
function test(){
    $config = Array(
            'protocol'=>'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '25',
            'SMTPAuth' => true,
            'smtp_user' => 'email@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password'
        );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    //$this->email->set_newline('\r\n');

    $this->email->from('email@gmail.com','Sender name');

    $this->email->to('email@micromerger.com');
    $this->email->subject('Test mail');
    $this->email->message('This is a test mail from codeigniter');
   //print_r($this->email);exit;
    if( ! $this->email->send()){
    //print_r("234");exit;
        echo "Your mail was sent successfully!!!";
    }
    else{
    //print_r("345");exit;
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```