# Codeigniter - email doesn't read config setting

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

We have a website built with the Codeigniter framework. This site has been working OK (~8 months) until last 2 weeks.

So we have a form, once the user submits the form, we insert the data to our MySQL database and send an email to the user. Now, the database part works fine. But the email function stopped working 2 weeks ago. And I'm sure I didn't change anything in the code.

I created a test for this purpose

```
public function test_email(){ 

    $this->load->config('email');
    $this->load->library('custom_email');

    $ddd = $this->load->config('email');  
    $data = array(
        //must have
        'recipient'         => 'test@test.com',
        'recipient_name'    => 'Test',
        'title'             => 'Ms',
        'subject'           => 'Email Test',    
        'admin_email'       => $this->config->item('auto_bcc_to'),
        "smtp" =>$this->config->item('smtp_host')
    );
    ch_printr($data);

    $this->custom_email->send('test_email',$data,TRUE);

}
```

and my libraries/custom_email.php

```
class custom_email {

    function __construct() {
        $this->ci = & get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->helper('html');
        $this->ci->load->library('email');
    }
    function send($type,$data,$debug_mode = FALSE){

        $data['site_name']  = $this->ci->config->item('site_name');
        $data['message']    = $this->ci->parser->parse('email/email--'.$type,$data,TRUE); 
       return $this->_send($data,$debug_mode);
    }
    private function _send($data,$debug_mode = FALSE){

        $this->ci->config->load("email");

        $email = $data['recipient'];

        $email_message = $data['message'];

        $subject = $data['subject'];

       $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
       $headers .= 'From: '.$this->ci->config->item('system_sender_name').'<'.$this->ci->config->item('system_sender_mail').'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: '.$data['recipient_name'].'<'.$data['recipient'].'>' . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

       if(mail($email, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $email_message, $headers)){    //error is pointed here
           return true; 
       }else{
          return false;
       }

    }
}
```

and config/email.php

```
$config = Array( 
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'webmaster@test.com', 
'smtp_pass' => 'myPassword',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'utf-8',
'crlf'      => "\r\n",       
'newline'   => "\r\n",       

'system_sender_mail'    => 'webmaster@test.com',
'system_sender_name'    => 'Webmaster',
'auto_bcc_to'           => 'admin@test.com'
);
```

Now, the email stopped working and we get this error

```
Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
Filename: libraries/custom_email.php
Line Number: 110
```

I tried to print_r the email config item (the smtp setting) and it retrieves the correct data. How should I proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At first sight your config looks all right. Are you absolutely sure your mail server is running and correctly processing emails? Check your logs to be sure.

Comment: @SolarBear hi thanks for your comment. yes i'm sure our mail server is doing well. we can use our office emails (same server) with no problem. please correct me if i'm wrong - but the problem on the system is, the custom_email() doesn't read the email config array. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: we use google mail server fyi

Answer (score 2):

Thiss function is working for me.

```
function email_send(){
    $config = Array(
            'protocol'=>'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '25',
            'SMTPAuth' => true,
            'smtp_user' => 'email@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password'
        );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->email->from('test@gmail.com');

    $this->email->to('test1@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Test mail');
    $this->email->message('This is a test mail from codeigniter');
   if( ! $this->email->send()){
        echo "Your mail was sent successfully!!!";
    }
    else{
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @pakistanimoon, yes if i use your code, it works ok. but I need to use custom_email (my libraries/custom_email.php) to send. I tried yours $config (edited directly to the config/email.php) but it still shows same error

Comment: then i think so you need to mention SMTP host and SMTP port in php.ini file. you can set this on runtime with ini_set() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php http://lzone.de/PHP-ini_set-Examples

Answer (score 0):

your email setting and port should be changed like

```
$config = Array( 
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'smtp_port' => 25,
'SMTPAuth' => true,
'smtp_user' => 'webmaster@test.com', 
'smtp_pass' => 'myPassword',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'utf-8', 
);
```

Comment: also have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627400/codeigniter-email-browser-keeps-on-loading/28627880#28627880

Comment: put it on any free live server may b localhost issue and also change your account settings from google https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: hi @imran qamer, in fact i'm not using this on my localhost but on our live web server.

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful I  have found a better way to test email sending in codeigniter.

I am using [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/)  api to send email and have testing , its as simple as using smtp setting , but  this helps keep inbox clean  and on production you just have  change smtp detiils .

If  you are writing any test ,  you can use this  api lib  i have created.

look into this Mailtrap [lib](https://github.com/jaiwalker/mailtrap)